# WPF: how to add an image dynamically to datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF app with 2 windows.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Procect1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Procect1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Lista pacjentów"  Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid  Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfPeople}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding  Name}" Header="Imię" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Surname}" Header="Nazwisko" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IdNumber}" Header="Pesel"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Age}" Header="Wiek" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Zdjęcie">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Canvas>
            <Button Canvas.Right="20" Canvas.Top="30" Height="50" Width="80" FontSize="18" Command="{Binding Window2Open}">Dodaj</Button>
            <Button Canvas.Right="20" Canvas.Top="100" Height="50" Width="80" FontSize="18" Command="{Binding Serialize}">Serializuj</Button>
            <Button Canvas.Right="20" Canvas.Top="170" Height="50" Width="80" FontSize="18" Command="{Binding DeSerialize}">Załaduj</Button>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
namespace Procect1
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        
        public ViewModel()
        {
            ListOfPeople = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        }

        

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private void ChangeDataExecute()
        {
            
        }

        private void Window3OpenExecute()
        {
            Window3 Window3 = new Window3(this);
            Window3.Show();
        }

        private void Window2OpenExecute()
        {
            Window2 Window2 = new Window2(this);
            Window2.Show();
        }

        private void AddPhotoExecute()
        {
            foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
            {
                if (window.GetType() == typeof(Window2))
                {

                    BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                    myBitmapImage.BeginInit();

                    OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
                    op.Title = "Select a picture";
                    op.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
                      "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
                      "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png";
                    if (op.ShowDialog() == true)
                   {

                       (window as Window2).imgPhoto.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(op.FileName));
                        
                        
                   }
                }
           }
        }

        private void AddPersonToListExecute()
        {
            foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
            {
                if (window.GetType() == typeof(Window2))
                {

                    ListOfPeople.Add(new Person()
                    {
                        Name = (window as Window2).textBox_FirstName.Text,
                        Surname = (window as Window2).textBox_LastName.Text,
                        IdNumber = (window as Window2).textBox_IdNumber.Text,
                        Age = (window as Window2).textBox_Age.Text,
                        Image = (window as Window2).imgPhoto.Source
                    }) ;
                    
                    (window as Window2).Close();
                }
            }
        }

        private void SerializeExecute()
        {
            Stream stream = File.OpenWrite(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Serialization1.xml");
            XmlSerializer people = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Person>));
            people.Serialize(stream, ListOfPeople);
            stream.Close();
        }

        private void DeSerializeExecute()
        {
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Person>));
            TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Serialization1.xml");
            ListOfPeople = (ObservableCollection<Person>)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
            textReader.Close();
        }

        public ICommand ChangeData { get { return new RelayCommand(ChangeDataExecute); } }
        public ICommand Window2Open { get { return new RelayCommand(Window2OpenExecute); } }
        public ICommand Window3Open { get { return new RelayCommand(Window3OpenExecute); } }
        public ICommand AddPersonToList { get { return new RelayCommand(AddPersonToListExecute); } }
        public ICommand Serialize { get { return new RelayCommand(SerializeExecute); } }
        public ICommand DeSerialize { get { return new RelayCommand(DeSerializeExecute); } }
        public ICommand AddPhoto { get { return new RelayCommand(AddPhotoExecute); } }
        public ObservableCollection<Person> ListOfPeople
        {
            get
            {
                return listOfPeople;
            }
            set
            {
                listOfPeople = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ListOfPeople");
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Person> listOfPeople;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

**Person**

```
namespace Procect1
{
    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
            }
        }

        public string Surname
        {
            get
            {
                return surname;
            }
            set
            {
                surname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Surname));
            }
        }

        public string IdNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return idNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                idNumber = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IdNumber));
            }
        }

        public string Age
        {
            get
            {
                return age;
            }
            set
            {
                age = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Age));
            }
        }

        public ImageSource Image
        {
            get
            {
                return Image;
            }
            set
            {
                image = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Image));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private string name;
        private string surname;
        private string idNumber;
        private string age;
        private ImageSource image;       
    }
}
```

In the Window2, I write first name, last name, id number, age, and I add a photo of a person.
In the MainWindow, I have to show the information about added people in datagrid. My problem is that I don't know what to do the app would show added photo in datagrid- in class Person.cs shows up the OverflowException after adding person(`return Image`)

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Could you please include the error in your question?

Comment: When I add a new person the app stops and shows the OverflowException

Comment: Edit your question and add that. it's important. it can help trace your problem.

Comment: return Image should be return image (the backing field)

Comment: That was it. Thanks :)